# What does start value mean in ffprobe output?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

What does **start value** mean in the ffprobe output?
For example:   Duration: 00:00:36.60, start: 0.066733, bitrate: 0 kb/s
Someone explain to me what the value mean, and how ffprobe calculated?

Comment: It is the earliest timestamp of a media packet in the file.

Comment: Hello! I would really appreciate it if you could send me a detailed documentation about it. I understand what you've shared, but I haven't been able to find any official documentation yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all streams necessarily start at 0. At least one stream must (obviously) start at 0, but other streams can start later. For example, if you have a video that has credits or several black frames at the start or end with no need for sound, there is no reason to have a silent audio track running during those portions of the video.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have accepted your answer. My final question is: How does FFmpeg choose the relevant stream? I assume there is a logic that determines the "starting stream" for a specific container. For example, for MP4 files, this is a video stream, and for MP3 files, this is an audio stream. Is my assumption correct? If not, could you please provide me with more details?